# Twig the same block in different included files

Tags: symfony, include, twig, block

I have problem with included files. In my layout.html.twig I have scripts.js at the end body section before {% block script %}{% endblock %}. When file extending layout and use script block, its ok, but when use this block and include file whose use the same block, then is problem. Rendered page has all javascripts, but in different places.

For example:

page.html.twig

```
...
There is page.html.twig
{% include 'file.html.twig' with {'something': 'something'} %}
After include file.html.twig
..
{% block script %}
<script src="file1.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

file.html.twig

```
There is file.html.twig
{% block script %}
<script src="file2.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Then rendered page look like this:

```
There is page.html.twig
There is file.html.twig
<script src="file2.js"></script>
After include file.html.twig
<script src="file1.js"></script>
```

I want have all javascript files in one place, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to 'embed' instead of 'include'.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html

With embedded, you can choose blocks to include.

**Ps** : If you override a block, you can get the parent block content in using parent() :

```
{% block script %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock script %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{% block %}` tag and the inheritance system work only with layouts and `{% extends %}`. It is not meant to be used with includes, so the **script** block in your included **file.html.twig** does not merge with **page.html.twig**.

One solution would be to set a an argument to you included file.

file.html.twig

```
{% if get == 'content' %}
    There is file.html.twig
{% endif %}
{% if get == 'script' %}
<script src="file2.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

page.html.twig

```
...
There is page.html.twig
{% include 'file.html.twig' with {'something': 'something', 'get': 'content'} %}
After include file.html.twig
..
{% block script %}
<script src="file1.js"></script>
{% include 'file.html.twig' with {'something': 'something', 'get': 'script'} %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to conform to a standard practice when dealing with included templates and inheritance (you can invent your own standard).

Try to compartmentalize your includes, I usually have a directory called 'partials' for includes, and 'fragments' for renders.  Each one belonging to a single collection of controller views.

One way I dealt with a similar problem to what you are having was to use a base template which covered the requirements of a specific set of views, each view template would extend it.  It may be somewhat wasteful to include the javascripts and stylesheets for the entire collection of views for a specific controller, but it is a) more efficient that including all assets everywhere and, b) I manage the view specific assets under a single base template.

So long as the views have a dependency on that base template the structure wouldn't break.

Think of Twig templates as PHP classes (they compile to classes anyway).  A class can inherit from one chain of parents.  What you are trying to do is treat two sub-classes as a single child of a super class, overriding the same method at the same time.  Simply can't be done. An include is closer to a child property, with is own rules and properties.  The included template is less dependent on the includer than vice-versa, so it is impossible for it to inherit from it conventionally.

Comment: Can you tell me more about your template/file structure? (what file inherit what?). Could you show me basic abstract template and some examples?

Comment: Its rather a large example, but I can explain it for your case.  Encapsulate the context of the templates you are using, then create a common (but minimal) base template that works for all of them.  Place your scripts in this template.  Then have your views extend this template.  Its more or less then same as you are probably doing already with your global template (if you have one), merely creating multiple layers.